# SQL : REGEX MATCH - Character followed by numbers inside quotes

Tags: sql, regex, numbers, character

I have a column in sql which holds value inside double quotes like "P1234567" , "P1234" etc..

I need to identify only columns which start with letter P and is followed by seven digits (numbers) only. I tried where column like'"P[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"' but it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone please correct me or point me to a thread which can help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

How about using length and isnumeric:

```
Select
  *
from
  mytable
where
  mycolumn like '"P%'
  and len(mycolumn) = 10 --2 chars for quotes + 1 for 'P' + 7 for the digits
  and isnumeric(substring(mycolumn, 3, 7))=1
```

This answer is for SQL Server, other DBMS's may have a different syntax for length

Comment: thanks this works. I am using SQL server and do not have any extensions. the only change I had to make to the above was and isnumeric(substring(mycolumn, 3, 7))=1

Comment: @PRC excellent, glad it does.  Be sure to check the mark below the voting arrows to mark as answer.  It lets others with the same problem know what solved it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL has no regex support, but most SQL engines have regex extensions added to them on top of the standard SQL. So, for example, if you're using MySQL then you'd do this:

```
... WHERE column REGEXP '^"P[0-9]{7}"'
```

And if you're using Postgres then that would be:

```
... WHERE column ~ '^"P[0-9]{7}"'
```

(updated to match the double-quote part of the question, I'd misunderstood that to begin with)